# Evading button, but in a clean way

Tags: c#, winforms, algorithm, visual-studio-2012

I am making a test program in C# to learn about WinForms. The principle is, I have a UserControl of 640x480, with a button. When the cursor approach the button, I move it away.

I also detect when the button is dangerously near the limits of the UserControl, and make the button "jump" on the other side of the cursor, but is there a way to make it in a clean way (the button move escaping the cursor, without going out of the winform, and toward the center ?)

Current handling of UserControl's MouseMove event:

nX, nY, lastX, lastY are private int declared in the class.

```
private void UserControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(
            e.X < (this.button1.Location.X + this.button1.Size.Height  + 20) &&
            e.Y < (this.button1.Location.Y + this.button1.Size.Width + 20) && 
            e.X >= (this.button1.Location.X - 20) && 
            e.Y >= (this.button1.Location.Y - 20)
        )
        {
            nX = this.button1.Location.X + (e.X - lastX);
            nY = this.button1.Location.Y + (e.Y - lastY);
            if (nX < 20)
            {
                nX = nX + 80;
            }
            if (nY < 20)
            {
                nY = nY + 80;
            }
            if (nX > this.Size.Width - this.button1.Size.Width - 20)
            {
                nX = nX - 80;
            }
            if (nY > this.Size.Height - this.button1.Size.Height - 20)
            {
                nY = nY - 80;
            }
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(nX, nY);
        }
        lastX = e.X;
        lastY = e.Y;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include a check in ifs, so that you decide where the button is going to move relative to the center of the area. Something like `IF cursor is near the button AND cursor is between button and center AND button is near the edge THEN jump over towards the center`(Presenting the spirit of the algorithm, since code is irrelevant when discussing algorithms).

EDIT: It seems I missed the point of the question, sorry. Adding some randomness to the decision on the direction you move the button should do what you want in a convincing way, by moving up, down or diagonal with a preference towards the center, if possible. The logic is simple but the implementation needs a little typing. Note that the button can always be "cornered", so jumping is unavoidable.